# Retrieving data from TensorFlow object - list of booleans from correct_prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I am going over MNIST beginner tutorial (http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) and trying to get a boolean list of accurately predicted values from the correct_prediction tensor object. I am finding this confusing.

According to the tutorial
`correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))` suppost to give us a list of booleans:

> That gives us a list of booleans. To determine what fraction are
>   correct, we cast to floating point numbers and then take the mean. For
>   example, [True, False, True, True] would become [1,0,1,1] which would
>   become 0.75.

However, Trying `correct_prediction[0]` gives us `<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor at 0x111a404d0>`.
`type(correct_prediction)` gives us `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor` which is not a list. Calling `dir()` to see methods and then `correct_prediction.__getitem__(0)` gives us `<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor at 0x111386f50>`.

How do I access the list of predicted booleans and for that matter values of y, W and b? Should they be accessed somehow from tf.Session?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The tensor variables actually describe the computations that must be performed in order to obtain the values you are interested in.

In other words, the tensor defined with `correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))` doesn't contain the list of booleans, it contains the instructions for computing it in a tensorflow graph. In order to get the actual values, you need to tell tensorflow to compute it in a graph.

First, you need a `tf.Session` variable. A simple way to get it for testing in a interactive shell is `sess = tf.InteractiveSession()`, followed by variable initialization: `sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())`.

Then, you can call `sess.run(tensor_variable)` to compute the value of a given tensor (or a list of them). If your tensors include placeholders in their computations (which they usually do), you'll also have to provide a feed dictionary. This is exemplified in the tutorial.

Instead of `session.run()`, you can also call the `.eval()` method from tensors. This also needs that a default session exists.